# Android calendar view not showing month and year starting from lollipop 5.0

Tags: android, calendar, calendarview

Android calendarview not showing month and year from Lollipop

***Android CalendarView not Android DatePicker***

**I have used this code for below lollipop versions and it worked but from lollipop it is not working**

```
try
{
    Class<?> cvClass = calender.getClass();
    Field field = cvClass.getDeclaredField("mMonthName");
    field.setAccessible(true);

    try
    {
        TextView tv = (TextView) field.get(calender);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
catch (NoSuchFieldException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(this,
 R.style.AppBlackTheme,
 datePickerListener,
 cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), 
 cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
 cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

 datePicker.setCancelable(false);
 datePicker.setTitle("Select the date");

 return datePicker;
```

and that will give you this result on Lolipop and above versions:

[image: Calendar]

Hope you want a calendar view like this.

Or you can refer calenderview code from

https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid

Comment: hi EKIN i have asked for Android calandarView not Android  datapicker i don't know y its been downvoted

Comment: In lolipop above versions date picker is just like calendar view. First try it.

Comment: yes i tried date picker in previous apps but client specifically asked for calendar View in present app thats why

Comment: can you share a image of calendar view displaying in your application